# Building a employee directory

Tags: feeds

I am new to drupal but long time programmer. I'm trying to figure out how to create a directory similar to the one here (http://studentunion.okstate.edu/directory). Using feeds i can get the info to import but every entry goes into its own node. So question is using feeds how do i get all the entries to display on a single page.

Comment: Views is your friend! It can do everything on that page.

Comment: Yes everyone must say use views to create the list

Comment: Hello and welcome :) Please edit your title. While the body of your question is pretty reasonable, title hardly reflects what you are asking. It would make it easier to spot your question if you would post a one-sentence version of it as a title.

Comment: I got the views up and set to Feed source but i cant figure out how to tie that to the feed importer I made.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've got each employee in his/her own node, you can use views to show pages or blocks/panels with all employees (or certain employees depending on the filters you set on the view).